# Does a 'standalone' labelled statement have a purpose?

Tags: java, break

I'm able to compile and run the following code fragment, but I can't add any further code to it, in order to utilise the labelled statement.  Consequently, am I right in thinking that there is no logical use for such a statement?  (Java allows me to do this, which is why I ask.)

```
statement: System.out.print("This represents a \'standalone\' statement.");
```

Also, I'm learning Java, and discovered (just for some "trivial fun" only) that Java allows the following code fragments to compile OK.

```
labelID: System.out.println("Label identifiers are allowed to be - ");
labelID: System.out.println("the same.");

// Labels can be "chained together", and you can "break out of" any of them.
label1:
label2:
label3: break label1;  // Can be break label1, 2, or 3.

// Labels can be associated with "null statements"
label: {}
label: ;
```

Comment: Java also allows `(0+0+0+0+0+0+1)`though there is no practical use for it. So what?

Comment: +1 for the question, I am looking forward to learn something new today...

Answer (score 1):

Classic example is:

```
outer: while (...) {
    inner: while (...) {
        if (...) break outer;
    }
}
```

I guess letting them be anywhere was easier from compiler front end (lexer/parser) point of view. Not for anything practical. I will delete my answer once someone posts an impressive counter example :)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is this is a reminiscence of some historical intention of standardizing control flow in Java using `goto` and labels, that hadn't reach public releases of Java.

I'm thinking about this in conjunction with the `goto` keyword, which is still reserved in Java, but there is no valid syntax that includes it.